# How can i add two image from two different inputs on single page in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to upload two images in database at once submit attempt from single form that have two different file input fields.
I tried but its not working when i try to show result using print_r it gives a single file name for both input fields. How can i do it perfectly in codeigniter. please help for your reference i am uploading my code. you if any error please let me know.

### HTML Form Code

```
<form id="form_edit" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(" admin/aboutus/update/".$aboutus->id); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
            <input type="text" name="imgtitle" title="About Us Image Title" class="form-control  input-sm" value="<?php echo set_value('imgtitle', $aboutus->imgtitle); ?>" placeholder="Image Title" required="required">
            <?php echo form_textarea(['rows'=>'15', 'name'=>'imgdetail','title'=>'About Us Image Description','class'=>'form-control mptop input-sm','required'=>'required','value'=> set_value('detail', $aboutus->imgdetail)]); ?>
            <input type="file" name="img" title="About Us Image" class="form-control input-sm">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
            <input type="text" title="About Us Title" class="form-control input-sm" name="title" value="<?php echo set_value('title', $aboutus->title); ?>" placeholder="Type left side title of about us of maximum 15 characters" required="required">
            <?php echo form_textarea(['rows'=>'15', 'name'=>'detail','title'=>"About Us Detail",'class'=>'form-control mptop input-sm mptop','required'=>'required','value'=> set_value('detail', $aboutus->detail)]); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
            <input type="text" name="img_2title" title="About Us Image Title" class="form-control  input-sm" value="<?php echo set_value('imgtitle', $aboutus->img_2title); ?>" placeholder="Image Title" required="required">
            <?php echo form_textarea(['rows'=>'15', 'name'=>'img_2detail','title'=>'About Us Image Description','class'=>'form-control mptop input-sm','required'=>'required','value'=> set_value('detail', $aboutus->img_2detail)]); ?>
            <input type="file" name="img_2" title="About Us Image" class="form-control input-sm">
            <!-- id="detail" -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 mptop rmzero rpZero">
            <div class="btn-group pull-right text-right">
                <a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/dashboard');?>" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Back</a>
                <!-- <a href="<?= base_url('fassets/images/aboutus/'.$aboutus->img); ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" name="preview" id="save"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Preview</a> -->
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="submit" id="save"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

### My Codeigniter Control Code

```
public function update($id)
{

    $res = array();     
    //form field validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required|max_length[15]');
    if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
        echo json_encode(array('mes' => 'text-danger', 'msg' => validation_errors('')));
        exit;
    }   
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('detail', 'Detail', 'required|max_length[2000]'); 
    if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
        echo json_encode(array('mes' => 'text-danger', 'msg' => validation_errors('')));
        exit;
    }   
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('imgtitle', 'Image Title', 'required|max_length[15]');
    if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
        echo json_encode(array('mes' => 'text-danger', 'msg' => validation_errors('')));
        exit;
    }   
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('imgdetail', 'Image Description', 'required');
    if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
        echo json_encode(array('mes' => 'text-danger', 'msg' => validation_errors('')));
        exit;
    }   
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('img_2title', 'Second Image Title', 'required|max_length[15]');
    if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
        echo json_encode(array('mes' => 'text-danger', 'msg' => validation_errors('')));
        exit;
    }   
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('img_2detail', 'Second Image Description', 'required');
    if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
        echo json_encode(array('mes' => 'text-danger', 'msg' => validation_errors('')));
        exit;
    }   

    $config['upload_path'] = 'fassets/images/aboutus';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
    //$config['file_name'] = $_FILES['img']['name'];
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    //Load upload library and initialize configuration
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);        
        // echo $image_path; exit;      
    if((!$this->upload->do_upload('img')) && (!$this->upload->do_upload('img_2')))
    {
        $userData = array(
            'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'detail' => $this->input->post('detail'),   
            'imgtitle' => $this->input->post('imgtitle'),
            'imgdetail' => $this->input->post('imgdetail'), 
            'img_2title' => $this->input->post('img_2title'),
            'img_2detail' => $this->input->post('img_2detail')          

        );
        //Pass user data to model
        $insertUserData = $this->AboutusModel->update($userData, $id);
    }
    else
    {

        $userData = array(
            'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'detail' => $this->input->post('detail'),   
            'imgtitle' => $this->input->post('imgtitle'),
            'imgdetail' => $this->input->post('imgdetail'),
            'img_2title' => $this->input->post('img_2title'),
            'img_2detail' => $this->input->post('img_2detail'),             
            'img' =>  $this->upload->data('file_name'),
            'img_2' =>  $this->upload->data('file_name')
        );
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($userData);
        exit;
        //Pass user data to model
        $insertUserData = $this->AboutusModel->update($userData, $id);
    }
        //Storing insertion status message.
    if($insertUserData){
        $res = array(
            'mes' => 'text-success',
            'msg' => "Record has been saved successfully.",
        );
        echo json_encode($res);                     
    } else {
        $res = array(
            'mes' => 'text-danger',
            'msg' => "Oops! Something went wrong.",
        );
        echo json_encode($res);
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `$this->upload->data('file_name')`, you are getting only the last uploaded file name. You're missing the first one. To solve this simple issue, store both filenames in variables to use after both files have successfully been uploaded.

**Before:**

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

**Add:**

```
$img1 = $_FILES['img']['name'];
$img2 = $_FILES['img_2']['name'];
```

**Replace:**

```
'img' =>  $this->upload->data('file_name'),
'img_2' =>  $this->upload->data('file_name')
```

**With:**

```
'img' =>  $img1,
'img_2' =>  $img2
```

Another Issue:

In your current code, if your first upload succeeds the second will fail. To prevent that.

**Replace:**

```
if((!$this->upload->do_upload('img')) && (!$this->upload->do_upload('img_2')))
```

**With:**

```
$upload1_ok = $this->upload->do_upload('img');
$upload2_ok = $this->upload->do_upload('img_2');

if($upload1_ok == false && $upload2_ok == false)
```

Comment: Its done Dear @Karlo Kokkak But one issue persisit now its uplaod the both images name in database. But not upload both images in folder path it only upload first image in Folder..

Comment: On upload success, can you do `print_r($_FILES);` ? Does it show an error number?

Comment: Array
(
    [img] => Array
        (
            [name] => 3.jpeg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php3337.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 230038
        )

    [img_2] => Array
        (
            [name] => 2.jpeg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php3338.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 41805
        )

)

Comment: Updated my answer again. Last part please.

Comment: Its done Dear @Karlo We are just updating name in database, We are not uploading files,

Comment: Does my recent answer fixed the last issue?